# How to align text like a trapezoid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the sample html code

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px">
    12345 1234 1234 1234 123 12345 1234 1234 123 1234 12345
</div>
```

And I want the effect like this:

```
12345 1234 1234
1234 1234 123
12345 1234
1234 1234
123 1234
12345
```

or

```
12345
123 1234
1234 1234
12345 1234
1234 1234 123
12345 1234 1234
```

or

```
12345 1234 12345
 1234 1234 235
  12345 123 1234
   1234 123 212
    123 1234 12
     1234 12345
```

I have tried using `text-align` but the result is not my expected.

How can I do this effect without adding many of `<br>` and `$nbsp`, or adding many of `<div style="margin...">` by hard code?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that uses a fixed width font, or one that will work with any font? Is the enclosing `<div>` subject to any resizing at any point, or will it always be a fixed size?

Comment: The font is fixed but it may need to changed in the future. Actually, I want to put the font to match background image which contains several trapezoid.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I do this effect without adding many of `<br>` and `&nbsp`, or adding many of `<div style="margin...">` by hard code?

You can't. Same goes for heart-shaped, giraffe-shaped, etc. DOM elements are pretty much rectangular.

You'l have to do something like using Javscript. You weren't very specific on the requirements (monospace font, keeping words together, etc.), but here is one example.

```
<div id="trapezoid" style="width:100px;height:100px"></div>

<script>
    var data = '12345 1234 1234 1234 123 12345 1234 1234 123 1234 12345';
    var lines = [];
    data.split(' ').reduce(function(str, word, i, array) {
        str += word;
        if(lines.length === 0 || str.length > lines[lines.length-1].length || i === array.length - 1) {
            lines.push(str);
            return '';
        }
        return str;
    }, '');
    document.getElementById('trapezoid').innerHTML = lines.join('<br>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is **not** a standard solution, and for the current year at least this would not be applicable to most users, but to do that you can use some CSS cutting edge features like "*CSS Shape Modules*".

If you are using Chrome a way to enable CSS regions (Chrome 20+) is going to *chrome://flags* and enable *Experimental Web Platform features*.
A very simple test page could look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CSS Exclusions - Shape inside</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style type="text/css">
        #trapezoid {
            float: center;
            margin-top: 1em;
            width: 60em;
            height: 30em;
            -webkit-hyphens: auto;
            -webkit-shape-inside: polygon(0 0, 15% 0, 10% 20%, 0 20%);
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="trapezoid">
      12345 1234 1234 1234 123 12345 1234 1234 123 1234 12345  
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And this is what comes out:

[image: HTML-CSS output]

You can look at some more examples here: http://adobe.github.io/web-platform/samples/css-exclusions/basic/shape-inside-simple.html

Comment: Just for the records, I just tried the code on Canary and it doesn't seem to work while in Chrome it does, I'm puzzled